# SQL query - multiple inner join

Tags: sql

I have very limited knowledge in SQL, but I have to create a report query (in EPDM*) and I'm lost with INNER JOIN :)

*EPDM is a Project Data Management software, and it has a report generator. This needs a formatted query file.

This is a working query file content:

```
@[ListAllDoc] 
§Name [List all documents] 
§Company [Econ] 
§Description [This query lists all documents] 
§Version [1.1] 
§Arguments
[
  ProjectID pProjectID [1] [Select search folder. E.g "$\Documents", or browse for folder.]
]
§Sql 
[ 
SELECT D.Filename as 'File Name', P.Path As 'Path'
FROM Projects AS P 
INNER JOIN DocumentsInProjects AS DP ON P.ProjectID = DP.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Documents AS D ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID}
Order By P.Path ASC, D.Filename ASC
]
```

The goal is a file list of a specified path with columns **filename** + **path** + **username** (of latest revision)

The data is stored the database as you see below (table and columns):

- **Documents** => DocumentID, ProjectID, Filename, LatestRevisionNo
- **DocumentsInProjects** => ProjectID, Path, DocumentID
- **Revisions** => RevNr, DocumentID, UserID
- **Users** => UserID, Username

The connection between the documents and its path is the DocumentsInProjects table with ProjectID column.

There are multiple revisions on the documents, and I'd liket to get the UserID from the revision table when the Documents.DocumentID = Revisions.DocumentID and Documents.LatestRevisionNo = Revisions.RevNr (user of the latest revision).

**Sample data:**

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Documents                                            |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------------+
| DocumentID | ProjectID | Filename | LatestRevisionNo |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------------+
| 100        | 10        | Test.txt | 3                |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------------+

+------------------------------------------------+
| DocumentsInProjects                            |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+
| ProjectID           | Path        | DocumentID |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+
| 10                  | D:\TestPath | 100        |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+

+-----------------------------+
| Revisions                   |
+-------+------------+--------+
| RevNr | DocumentID | UserID |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 1     | 10         | 55     |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 2     | 10         | 46     |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 3     | 10         | 32     |
+-------+------------+--------+

+-------------------+
| Users             |
+--------+----------+
| UserID | Username |
+--------+----------+
| 55     | Peter    |
+--------+----------+
| 46     | Mike     |
+--------+----------+
| 32     | Lucy     |
+--------+----------+
```

With the sample data above I'd like to get the result:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+
| File Name | Path        | User |
+-----------+-------------+------+
| Test.txt  | D:\TestPath | Lucy |
+-----------+-------------+------+
```

Here is where I am now, but this doesn't work of course :D

*{pProjectID} is a variable taken from selection.*

```
SELECT D.Filename As 'File Name', P.Path As 'Path', U.Username as 'User'
FROM Projects AS P
INNER JOIN DocumentsInProjects AS DP ON P.ProjectID = DP.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Documents AS D ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
INNER JOIN Revisions AS R ON D.DocumentID = R.DocumentID AND D.LatestRevisionNo = R.RevNr
INNER JOIN Users AS U ON U.UserID = D.UserID
WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID}
```

please help me to correct this :)

**UPDATE -> SOLUTION**
Thank you for all of you to helped me, even is my question was not well specified and contains errors, missing elements (sorry for that) :)
@davidc2p helped me the most with the code correction, based upon that I made a little modification and this code works well:

```
SELECT D.Filename As 'File Name', P.Path As 'Path', U.Username As 'User'
FROM Projects AS P
INNER JOIN DocumentsInProjects AS DP ON P.ProjectID = DP.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Documents AS D ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
INNER JOIN Revisions AS R ON D.DocumentID = R.DocumentID AND D.LatestRevisionNo = R.RevNr
INNER JOIN Users AS U ON R.UserID = U.UserID
WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and an explanation of what you *want* would all be helpful.

Comment: "_this doesn't work of course :D_" <- not a problem description. why not? what happens? why is that wrong?

Comment: ".. of course" .. because I am a beginner and not familiar with using inner join :)
The only error message from SQL server what I get:
"Error executing the query
...
<No error message returned.>"

I guess the problem is with the inner joins

Comment: `INNER JOIN Documents AS D DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID` --> You forgot an `on` here. Is this a typo or could this be your mistake ?

Comment: @Gary this was a mistake, I correct this

Comment: What is EPDM? What implementation of SQL does it use? Please [edit] your post to clarify/tag this.

Comment: Also remove the `WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID}`, that isnt the way to pass a parameter and if still doesnt work remove all and start adding JOIN one each time until you found the error

Comment: Not all databases support single quotes for aliases. Also not all databases support "AS" keyword between table_name and alias_name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I put some sample data to the post

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID} is OK in this report system, I have a shorter working version and that query runs well with it.

Comment: @VBoka I have a shorter working version of this query and there is OK the single quote

Comment: @norbre, please show us that shorter version that worked and also, where is the Projects table ?

Comment: @VBoka I updated my post, the working full code is on the begining of it

Comment: I missed DocumentID field from DocumentsInProjects table, I've updated (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about primary keys or unique keys should be provided. But considering what you sent your query has some errors:

There's no userID on table Documents. Your query should access UserID from Revisions table.

Also, DocumentID is not a field from DocumentsInProjects, you should link this table with ProjectID and therefore get all documents associated with a project.

Also, path is from DP not P.

```
SELECT D.Filename As 'File Name', DP.Path As 'Path', U.Username as 'User'
FROM Projects AS P

    INNER JOIN DocumentsInProjects AS DP 
    ON P.ProjectID = DP.ProjectID

    INNER JOIN Documents AS D 
    ON DP.ProjectID= D.ProjectID

    INNER JOIN Revisions AS R 
    ON D.DocumentID = R.DocumentID 
    AND D.LatestRevisionNo = R.RevNr

    INNER JOIN Users AS U 
    ON U.UserID = R.UserID

WHERE P.ProjectID = {pProjectID}
```

There are probably some other mistakes. It would be easier if you provided also temporary table creation with a set of sample data.

Also depending on unicity, your result might show duplicate information.

Comment: Some very nice things OP should take note of.

Comment: You are right in lot of things, and my mistake: DocumentsInProjects has DocumentID .. I correct this in my post

Comment: @davidc2p I write back this: INNER JOIN Documents AS D ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID 
... but still doesn't work

Comment: @nobre Same error ? Or no result ? If you are not getting any result then it has to do with your data and not the code

Comment: @Gary unfortunatelly when the code contains errors, I get only an empty error message. I get result only when the code is right

Comment: I GOT THE SOLUTION (I put it at the end of my original post)
Thank you for all of you to helped me, even is my question was not well specified and contains errors, missing elements (sorry for that) :)
@davidc2p helped me the most with the code correction, based upon that I made a little modification and now the code works well.